What does "pastels and plastics of Los Angeles" mean?
In Barbie (2023), the narrator narrates this line when Barbie leaves Barbie Land
for the Real World:

Narrator: Barbie left behind the pastels and plastics of Barbie Land
for the pastels and plastics of Los Angeles.

What does "pastels and plastics of Los Angeles" mean ?

Soft focus false reality?

Pastels are a color scheme:

Barbieland, in the movie, is distinctively colorful. Pastels also have the connotation of being emotionally positive, in a way. “Leaving behind the pastels of Barbieland” could subtly hint that Barbieland is a cheery place, a beneficial environment. Of course, Barbieland is made of plastic, so they’re “leaving behind the plastic”. By “plastics”, they could mean, “multiple kinds of plastic”, or “multiple things made of plastic”, or even, “multiple people, who are made of plastic”. Of course, “plastic” has a connotation of artificiality, in a way, so maybe the inhabitants of Barbieland are almost robotically happy.

The irony is that LA is also a land of pastels and plastics. It’s colorful, beachy, vibrant, comforting (supposedly, at least some parts):

but there are also plenty of “plastics”: fake people, artificially perfect people, celebrity culture, plastic surgery, etc:


